# How do I Change Force Touch "taptic" or haptic feedback on MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, bettertouchtool

I love my new MBP Retina but I would like to change the amount the Force Touch vibrates.  I know there are the settings called Light, Medium and Firm to change not only the amount it vibrates but also the intensity of the force required to actuate.  I am wondering if there is any way to turn the vibration of the Taptic Engine up even further to receive a more tactile click. Is this possible? Can I use BetterTouchTool to achieve this result? I tried to mess around with it a little bit but I don't think it works.

Comment: Maybe we need to switch hardware. [I want a lower click](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277306/), you want more click. My presumption is once you have the force at maximum, the hardware simply doesn't have enough weight to shake things more. Hopefully both of us can tweak things, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think the hardware has plenty of "weight to shake things more" because on the "Firm" click setting, the Force Touch vibrates quite a bit. I just wish that that was the default level of haptic feedback. (I could do without Force Touch; I just want a really solid "click" when I click.)

I really miss the mechanical button on my old Macbook Pro.