# Can the haptic feedback level be lowered on the ForceTouch trackpad for MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, trackpad, haptic-feedback

The haptic feedback on the Force Touch Trackpad is too loud/clicky for my preferences. I run macOS 10.12.3 (16D32) on the 15 inch TouchBar model MacBook Pro if that matters - but this persists to the 2018 hardware and macOS 10.14.4 well into the last few versions of Mojave.

If I disable force click, that turns off the haptic feedback entirely. I also have reduced it to the minimum force which helps, but is still too loud.

[image]

That's not what I'd like, though - I want force click enabled with a significantly reduced haptic force click sound.

Is there a setting to change this whether it's a hidden preference or adjustment or if it's something in the system preferences?

Comment: I'm guessing the [maximum level can't be increased](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202978/how-do-i-change-force-touch-taptic-or-haptic-feedback-on-macbook-pro) unless you installed custom hardware to increase the force, but hopefully there's a way to dial it down in software. Also, **I know** - first world problems, huh?

Comment: Seems to me that the sound is not coming from the speakers, so it seems to me that the haptic engine makes a physical sound as it actuates.  Much like the key presses on the keyboard.  I'm curious to see if this can be silenced too.  Great question.

Comment: According to [Apple's support docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352) and noted by several [reviews](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/11/review-cheapest-2016-macbook-pro-is-good-but-its-missing-all-the-cool-stuff/2/), the late 2016 MacBook Pro does not preserve the "Silent Clicking" option offered on the 12" MacBook; I have not heard if this is a software or hardware limitation. (As a MacBook owner, there is always a bit of audible noise generated upon clicking, so the missing option might not help as much as you'd like!)

Comment: @Merlin this trackpad doesn't physically move. There is no click other than haptic motors being commanded to vibrate. That being said, you link is the answer and I would select it if you post it in the answer section : - )

Comment: Yes, but the haptic actuators apparently cannot be turned off completely within macOS' Preferences: on any settings available, they'll still simulate a physical button click and generate the attendant noise, so there's no way to click in complete stealth. (Well, I guess there's tap-to-click.) Glad you liked it, but I was hoping someone would turn up with something better than my "Apple says there isn't" answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Apple's support docs](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352) and as also noted by several [reviews](https://arstechnica.com/apple/2016/11/review-cheapest-2016-macbook-pro-is-good-but-its-missing-all-the-cool-stuff/2/), the late 2016 MacBook Pro does not have the "Silent Clicking" option offered on the 12" MacBook and the Magic Trackpad 2.

(As an aside to ward off disappointment, Silent Clicking is not completely silent anyway: the actuators still trigger to generate the haptic effect and thus a small amount of attendant noise.)

Comment: I really miss this feature... It felt different than just tapping on your trackpad.